# eMailing list : each adress is confidential but anyone can "Reply All"

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, gmail

I am not sure I can explain properly because my English is not that good. So, I will use an example.

I, OP, want to contact several people. Let's have the sender (the OP), Alice and Bob.

- OP emails Alice & Bob
- Alice can reply to everybody (or just to OP)
- Bob can reply to everybody (or just to OP)
- Neither Alice nor Bob can reply to respectively Bob or Alice since they don't have their private email address.

How to hide Alice and Bob's addresses while allowing them to reply to everyone (OP, Alice, Bob) ?

What I have : company Outlook or Gmail. No problem opening new accounts for making it work, it's a one time need. I can ask stuff from the company Outlook administrator if required.

What I am doing right now : using BCC field from Outlook. But receivers can't reply all :(

What I hope for : creating a confidential mailing list so that people reply to the mailing list address confidential@mail_server and the server will broadcast or something.

How to do it with any emailing solution ?

Comment: You already mentioned the keyword you want to look for: mailing list (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_mailing_list). Set that up on the mailserver and use that as sender. Everyone can reply to it. Everyone only sees the name of your mailing list.

Comment: In mailing list I am used to, anyone can expand the list to see every address. So that's not what I am looking for

Comment: That is the common outlook/exchange version. The classic much older type does not expand in outlook (or any mail client). To the end user it literally is a single mail address. Nothing to expand,

Comment: Right! So how do I do that?

Comment: Install mailinglist software. Basically you do not use a regular mail server but also a list server. Mail gets sent to that single recipient (basically the same as a regular user via one regular mail adress). That list server (and its only adress) then mails all the subscribers of the list. Google on listserv or start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LISTSERV

Comment: Thank you! Just to be sure we understand, I can't do this with outlook or Gmail? Also could you add this as an answer so I can validate it once I confirm it works for my use case?

Comment: Yes and no, to both questions. 1. I can make that an answer, but I would write that a bit larger than what now is in comments. If noone has done so tomorrow I'll do that.  2. Can I di that with outlook? Sort of. You still need the listserv software installed somewhere. Preferably on the mail server or any other server which is reachable 24/7.  Not on your own laptop which is on 09:00-17:00. Well not unless you do not mind others have to wait until you are connected to the Internet.